# How do I calculate the mean of column with comma-separated string of numbers?

Tags: r

I want to find out the mean of each row for column "votes" but when I try to read that column in as a numeric value instead of a character it gives me an error. After that I dont know how to get r to understand what i want !

[image: data set]

Comment: Welcome to SO, Alessandra Bracci! Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info for good discussions on producing fully-reproducible questions. Thank you!

Comment: You can do `sapply(sapply(sapply(votes$Votes, strsplit, ",", USE.NAMES = F), as.numeric), sum)`. But an adequate answer can only be given if you share an example with data.

Comment: How about the issue is only about the import?

Answer (score 2):

When reading a CSV file where a field as comma-delimited numbers, it will always be string, it cannot be read as a number. This is because "what number" is ambiguous, so R will make you choose. There are such things as list-columns that will allow each field to be a list of numbers, but most vector-based functions will not work as smoothly on them.

Since it is likely to be read as numbers, we can split it manually with this:

```r
dat <- data.frame(Votes = c("4,5,3,5,1,4,4,5,6", "4,4,3,5,4,3,5,4", "5,4,6,5,3,4,1,4,6"))
dat
#               Votes
# 1 4,5,3,5,1,4,4,5,6
# 2   4,4,3,5,4,3,5,4
# 3 5,4,6,5,3,4,1,4,6
dat$Votes_mu <- sapply(strsplit(dat$Votes, ","), function(z) mean(as.numeric(z)))
dat
#               Votes Votes_mu
# 1 4,5,3,5,1,4,4,5,6 4.111111
# 2   4,4,3,5,4,3,5,4 4.000000
# 3 5,4,6,5,3,4,1,4,6 4.222222
```

Note: if there are any non-numbers (non-response or non-numeric characters), then `mean(as.numeric(.))` will produce an `NA`. If you want to ignore the non-numbers, then change the inner code to `mean(as.numeric(z), na.rm = TRUE)`.

---

### Extra: list-columns

FYI, the "list-column" thing in R can be a good way to store multiple values, especially when (as in this example) there are different amounts per row. In this case, we can do something like:

```r
dat$Votes2 <- lapply(strsplit(dat$Votes, ","), as.numeric)
dat
#               Votes                    Votes2
# 1 4,5,3,5,1,4,4,5,6 4, 5, 3, 5, 1, 4, 4, 5, 6
# 2   4,4,3,5,4,3,5,4    4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 3, 5, 4
# 3 5,4,6,5,3,4,1,4,6 5, 4, 6, 5, 3, 4, 1, 4, 6
```

And while they look really similar (albeit spaces), you can see the `str`uctural differences:

```r
str(dat)
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ Votes : chr  "4,5,3,5,1,4,4,5,6" "4,4,3,5,4,3,5,4" "5,4,6,5,3,4,1,4,6"
#  $ Votes2:List of 3
#   ..$ : num  4 5 3 5 1 4 4 5 6
#   ..$ : num  4 4 3 5 4 3 5 4
#   ..$ : num  5 4 6 5 3 4 1 4 6
```

This might be helpful if you need to find specific tokens (votes) in each element. For instance, if you wanted to know which rows had at least one `1` vote, then one could do:

```r
sapply(dat$Votes2, function(z) 1 %in% z)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

(where this method does not work with `dat$Votes`). Yes, this one example could use regex to find `1`s in `Votes`, so perhaps list-columns aren't necessary for your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two equivalent ways.

```r
dat <- data.frame(Votes = c("4,5,3,5,1,4,4,5,6", "4,4,3,5,4,3,5,4", 
                            "5,4,6,5,3,4,1,4,6"))

sapply(dat$Votes, \(x) mean(scan(textConnection(x), sep = ",")), USE.NAMES = FALSE)
#> [1] 4.111111 4.000000 4.222222

dat$Votes |>
  sapply(\(x) x |> textConnection() |> scan(sep = ",") |> mean(), USE.NAMES = FALSE)
#> [1] 4.111111 4.000000 4.222222
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Using `DF` in the Note at the end, scan each comma separated value by row (which for each row will create a numeric vector of those numbers) and then take the mean of that vector.

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(mean = mean(scan(text = y, sep = ",", quiet = TRUE))) %>%
  ungroup
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
      x y      mean
  <int> <chr> <dbl>
1     1 1,2,3   2  
2     2 4,5     4.5
3     3 7       7
```

**2)** Using only base R:

```
Mean <- function(x) mean(scan(text = x, sep = ",", quiet = TRUE))
transform(DF, mean = sapply(y, Mean))
```

**3)** Another base R approach:

```
transform(DF, 
  mean = rowMeans(read.table(text = y, fill = TRUE, sep = ","), na.rm = TRUE))
```

### Note

```
DF <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = c("1,2,3", "4,5", "7"))

> DF
  x     y
1 1 1,2,3
2 2   4,5
3 3     7
```